# How do you set a checkbox to true using pypdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to programmatically fill out a fillable pdf with python using pypdf. Here are the [docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I already have it working with normal text boxes:

```
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "Jeff Willams"})
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to deal with checkboxes. I've tried all of the following with no success:

```
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: True})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "True"})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "true"})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "On"})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "/On"})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "Yes"})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[i], {key: "/Yes"})
```

Is this even the right method to use for this? Please let me know if anyone has experience with this. Thanks.

Comment: I've looked at what the key is for each text box and I've used the value that you would expect based on what's in the key. For some reason it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to give it a try yourself here's the pdf I'm working with. https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-589.pdf

Comment: @Cole This type of question comes up once in a while. Sadly, there is no good bullet-proof answer as far as I know. Would you mind if I generalized your question a bit so that it would cover the other cases? I would call it "How do I (un)set checkboxes in PDF documents with Python?".

Comment: @MartinThoma I wouldn't mind at all in fact I would really appreciate it.